# Threading with ImageDrawings and freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, freezable

I have a problem creating an Image in a background-thread.
I have a main-icon (16x16 pixel) that should be merged with other icons, that can be an overlay. My code for this is this:

```
private void GenerateConnectionIcon()
{
    var dGr = new DrawingGroup();

    var newGroupItem = new ImageDrawing(_ConnectionIcon, new Rect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    newGroupItem.Freeze(); //Here it throws the expection

    dGr.Children.Add(newGroupItem);

    foreach (var anOverlay in _ConnectionIconOverlays)
    {
        dGr.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(anOverlay, new Rect(0, 0, 16, 16)));
    }

    dGr.Freeze();
    var finalIcon = new DrawingImage(dGr);

    finalIcon.Freeze();

    _ConnectionIconMerged = finalIcon;
}
```

The code quits in the third line because the calling thread is not the owner of the object.
I am a little bit confused about this, because the object is created one line above. The variable `_ConnectionIcon` is an `ImageSource` and is freezed.

The exact error message is `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`.

Why I cannot freeze an object, that is created one line above?

Comment: Search SO for `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it` and you will find a plethora of information about how to fix this (hint: `Dispatcher.Invoke()`)

Comment: What's `_ConnectionIcon`?

Comment: @DourHighArch as described: it is an ImageSource and contains the "base"-Image with a size of 16x16.

Comment: @PeterDuniho if I put it in a Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => newGroupItem.Freeze()); the newGroupItem.Freeze() still throws this error

Comment: OK, got it: Its really important to use Dispatcher.Invoke(...). I used newGroupItem.Dispatcher.Invoke(...) before.